# Error Handling in VBA for Word

Tags: vba

Even though I clearly have the error blocked off

```
For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    j = j + 1
    On Error GoTo hey:
    third_word(j) = sentence.Range.Words(3)
    sw(j) = sentence.Range.Words(2)
    tot_sent(j) = sentence.Range.Text

hey:

Next
```

The code is still throwing error 5941: the requested member collection does not exist.  That is exactly the type of error that I'm trying to except and make the code continue.  A lot of the paragraphs do not have a third word so I only want to put a sentence into the tot_sent array if the sentence has a third word.  The best way to do this is through error handling but it is not working.

Comment: Remove colon in GoTo statement

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: I'd say use the answer given by @MichaelO. - is generally better to avoid the error in the first place.  I think your error handling isn't get reset after it is raised - either move `hey:` out of the procedure by using `Exit Sub: hey: : Resume <another label in the code>: End Sub` or add `On Error Goto -1` after your `hey:` label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to check for conditions that may cause errors, but if you really want to use `On Error` then you need to `Resume` once an error has occurred.  If you don't `Resume` after processing the error, then you are still in "error handling" mode and any subsequent error cannot be trapped.

```
For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    j = j + 1
    On Error GoTo hey:
    third_word(j) = sentence.Range.Words(3)
    sw(j) = sentence.Range.Words(2)
    tot_sent(j) = sentence.Range.Text

ResumePoint:

Next

'...
'...

Exit Sub

hey:
    ' perform whatever processing is required for the error
    '...
    Resume ResumePoint

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    j = j + 1
    If sentence.Range.Words.Count > 2 Then
        third_word(j) = sentence.Range.Words(3)
        sw(j) = sentence.Range.Words(2)
        tot_sent(j) = sentence.Range.Text
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks that did it.  I should have been able to think of that.